# Is my code not working because i'm using an online IDE or is there an error?

Tags: python, text-editor

So, at school, I don't have access to Pycharm, Pyscripter, or Python it's self so I code using an IDE at school. Now, the problem is that I can't use inputs because I get an EOF error.

```
secret_number = 9
guessc = 0
guess_limit = 3
while guessc < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input('Guess: '))
    guessc += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print('You won!')
        break
```

I get an EOF error whenever I run this and I just wanted to know if that the problem is the IDE or faulty code.

Comment: Worked fine for me... and I won!

Comment: I do not see any error here. Can you please post the error here as well?

Comment: worked for me in python3

Comment: Ok, I'm going to like the IDE I'm using and the error. It's not a proper python text editor like I said an online IDE. Here's the website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php and here's the error:uwuTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    x = input("uwu")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
(it's an example)

Comment: Did you enter any text in the "STDIN" tab of the online IDE? That's where your input would be coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site runs your code non-interactively. So you need to specify all the `stdin` input for it beforehand, on the STDIN tab.

E.g. to simulate entering three numbers, you can specify (each newline will have the same effect as pressing Enter):

```
1
3
9
```

Also note that this input is not echoed into the output, unlike an interactive console.

Comment: Alright, I hope you don't mind if I ask and I probably sound like an idiot lmao, but what is stdin

Comment: @Pyscripter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)

Comment: @Pyscripter in the Stdin give the input values line by line

Answer (score 0):

PyScripter explains the situation beautifully. (BTW -- love the name PyScripter, because I love the free, open source Python IDE known as PyScripter.) But I want to add 2 cents worth: if you're struggling with a question like this one, your school is doing you a disservice. First of all, you can download and install all the Python stuff easily and free from Python.org, or in a slightly more slick fashion form places like ActiveState (no, you do not have to pay). But if your school hasn't told you that already, and they have not already explained the concept of STDIN, and you're struggling with the difference between the interactive environment and the runtime environment... I really wonder what they ARE doing! Is it too late to get your money back and take a real course? If you're working for an enterprise and can get them to pay the freight, my favorite approach these days is guided, self-paced learning, courses that allow you to go at your own pace, but which also have a real instructor at-the-ready, available via email to answer questions and offer guidance. Consider courses like this one: https://www.software-skills-training.com/Courses/python-programming-training-course.htm. I just finished the course, and it was terrific.

Comment: First off, to clarify I'm in middle school ^^, and  second I'm on a Chromebook that the school provided, so that makes it difficult to download but I'll definitely give it a check, And Pyscripter is superior

Comment: You may want to look at https://wsvincent.com/install-python3-chromebook/ or https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-windows-programs-on-chromebooks/

Answer (score 0):

Hah! Middle School! I never would have guessed!

You can download and run a Windows version of Python on a Chromebook if you first install something like WINE to act as a virtual OS on top of Chrome OS. I don't recommend this, as such a solution tends to be slow, cumbersome, and unreliable. You can likewise download a Linux-based Python for a Chromebook, but this too requires some intermediate software, and the solution is again slow, cumbersome, and unreliable.

You might take a look at Python Anywhere, which lets you create and run Python programs in the cloud, and their basic accounts are free. See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/details/education

Comment: It's a CRIME that your school system has you working on a Chromebook instead of a real computer. I am a big fan of all things Google, but there are a whole lot of things that you can do with a PC that you cannot do with cloud-based software.

Phineas Longstaff

Educator

https://www.software-skills-training.com

Comment: I'd assume that's good! I found a great website that allows commands and that is collaborative (so I and my friend can code together)  but thanks so much!